# PHP MYSQL mysql_fetch_array, loop. right way to go?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that returns a few rows, and I have the following lines of code to retrieve them:

```
$result_set = mysql_query($query);

while($net_biz_sub_data[]=
 mysql_fetch_array($result_set,MYSQL_ASSOC));
```

My question is what is the right way to retrieve that db query data without getting the last array empty ?
When I `count()` it is always num of rows + 1, and I would like to correct that.

Comment: The return value of count() is accurate. Arrays are zero indexed. Use < count() instead of <= count().

Comment: -0.25 for still using `mysql_query`.  What half-assed site/book/whatever is presenting that as an example of modern best practices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of the way the while loop works, you should do

```
while($dataz = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set))
{
    $net_biz_sub_data[] = $dataz;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$result_set = mysql_query($query);

while($net_biz_sub_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set)){
    //use $net_biz_sub_data here
}
```